# video upload using node.js and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

I am New to MongoDB and node.js. I want to know how can I store and fetch a video file in MongoDB using node.js? Any help will be appreciated. The code that I am using is:

```
app.post('/videos/new', function(req, res) {
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log('here i go');
    if(err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      ins = fs.createReadStream(files.file.path);
      console.log('insssssssssssss'+ins);
      ous = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/static/uploads/videos/' + files.file.filename);
      util.pump(ins, ous, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          next(err);
        } else { RegProvider.save({
           file: req.param(files.file.filename),
                   filename: req.param('filename')
                 }, function(error, docs) {
              res.redirect('/videos');
         });
        }
      });
      //console.log('\nUploaded %s to %s', files.file.filename, files.file.path);
      //res.send('Uploaded ' + files.file.filename + ' to ' + files.file.path);
    }
  });
});
```

The code to retrieve video files is:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var src_path = __dirname + '/static/uploads/vidoes/'
module.exports.list = function(callback) {
  fs.readdir(src_path,function(err, files){
    var ret_files = [];
    files.forEach(function(file) {
    ret_files.push('/uploads/videos/' + file);
    });
    console.log(ret_files);
    callback(err, ret_files);
  });
};
```

It is working fine, but doesn't store anything in MongoDB.

Comment: Please format your question and do some research before you post.

Comment: You are asking n Number Of Questions. Try to Ask the actual problem rather then asking so many questions.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev i have modified my question and also added the code that i am using.plz have a look at it and suggest any changes.

Comment: That's better, I re-opened. On your next tea break I suggest having a read of this excellent article: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian
is useful for string files in GridFS.

There are more examples of how to use the library than I can post here in the examples folder.

here:
https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian/blob/master/examples/mongolian_trainer.js

If you are uncertain of what GridFS is you can find out here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS

and thanks for improving your question.